Spring cloud gateway is not routing to the Websocket URL
I am trying to form web socket url in different application.yml environments. And use the path in my AppConstants.ts.
application-local.yml
id: llm
uri: wss://jpmchase.net/
predicates:
Path=/llm/**

filters:
RewritePath=/llm(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}

appconstants:
public static LLM_WEBSOCKET_URL = "llm/ws";
The LLM_WEBSOCKET_URL should populate wss://jpmchase.net/ws
